# Spring Validations + Swagger Documentation: Based on conditions or values of other fields

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I am designing a REST API for creating a new Employee.

Based on the Employee Type there will fields which are mandatory otherwise they are not.
e.g: All create API call should pass `employeeName`. But `contractVendorName` should be mandatory only if `employeeType=contractor`

Questions :

1. How to enforce such restriction using Spring Validations?
2. How to document such fields in Swagger?
3. If conditional validations is not supported, does it make sense to have different API for

   - createEmpoyee(ContractEmployee ce)
   - createEmpoyee(RegularEmployee re)
     In ContractEmployee object do the spring+swagger annotations to mark `contractVendorName` as mandatory.

Here I have taken just one field as an example, `contractVendorName`. I may have 5-6 fields which be optional or mandatory based on Employee type. I would prefer to use spring validations that way I don't have to write boilerplate code to check all the validations myself. Side effect of multiple employee type objects would be an increase in the APIs. Since each object type will need a separate API.

Any good suggestions on the approach to have separate objects + more apis versus since API and one object with all fields and do manual validations for each field based on the employee type?

```
public class EmployeeDTO {

      /**
       * Employee Type: full-time, part-time, permanent, contractor
       */
      @NotNull
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
      private String employeeType;

      /**
       * Mandatory field that is to be given by client 
       */
      @NotBlank
      @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
      private String employeeName;


      /**
       * How to make this field mandatory when employeeType =  contractor ?
       * Is this possible in Spring?
       * How to document it in Swagger?
       */
      private String contractVendorName;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Class level constraints to implement this. Read [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#section-class-level-constraints)

```
@Target({ TYPE, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = { VendorNameCheckValidator.class })
@Documented
public @interface VendorNameCheck {

    String message() default "{some.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}



public class VendorNameCheckValidator
        implements ConstraintValidator<ValidPassengerCount, EmployeeDTO> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(VendorNameCheck constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(EmployeeDTO dto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return true;
        }

        return !"contractor".equals(dto.getEmployeeType()) || isNotEmpty(dto.getContractVendorName());
    }
}
```